# Files are uploaded and downloaded successfully but able to open on the server

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-5.5

I am trying upload a file on server by using below lines of code.

```
    $.ajax({
                    url: '../common/uploadAllFiles.php?root=../student/certificates/', 
                    dataType: 'text', 
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: form_data,                         
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(php_script_response){
                        var document_unique_name = php_script_response;
                        $('#file-unique-name').val(document_unique_name);    
                        $('#upload-file_help').addClass("hide");   
                        $('#upload-file-div').removeClass("has-error");          
                    }
            });
```

In uploadAllFiles.php file, the code is written as

```
 <?php
        $uniqId = uniqid('file_');
        $root = $_REQUEST['root'];

        $target_file = "uploads/".basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

       if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) 
       {
          echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
       }
       else if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 10000000) 
       {
         echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
       }
       else 
       {   
          if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $root.$uniqId.".".$imageFileType))
           {
              echo $uniqId.".".$imageFileType;
           }
       }
    ?>
```

For downloading files, the code is written as

```
  function downloadCertificate(document_unique_name,document_actual_name) 
  {   
      window.location =  '../common/downloadFile.php?document_unique_name='+document_unique_name+'&document_actual_name='+document_actual_name; 
  }
```

in downloadFile.php, the code is written as

```
       <?php
        $fileName = $_REQUEST['document_unique_name'];
        $downloadFileName = $_REQUEST['document_actual_name'];
        $filePath = "../student/certificates/".$fileName;

        if(file_exists($filePath)) 
        {
           header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
           header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$downloadFileName);
           ob_clean();
           flush();
           readfile($filePath);
           exit;
       }
     ?>
```

On the local machine, these codes are working fine. But on the server, the files are uploaded in the certificates folder. When user clicks on the download file, it gets downloaded. When user clicks on that file in order to read, that file does not open. Note that in certificates folder of server, if we download that files from ftp and open it, it gets opened. I think the issue is in the download code. I am not able to trace where is the issue.

Please help !!!

Comment: Have you check by **URL** of image in your browser that it is showing or not?

Comment: sorry i m not getting it... Please explain

Comment: What file extensions do you want to read ?

Comment: jpeg, png, docx txt. jpg

Comment: Have you try to run image url in browser?

Comment: yes i have debugged it in on the server, i found that the main issue is at time of upload, the parameter document_unique_name gets missing("ReferenceError: php_script_response is not defined"),   so when document_unique_name gets saved as blank value in the database. So at time of download,  document_unique_name is missing, so it is not able find the actual file name.

Comment: I strongly feel the issue is at the time of ajax upload.

Comment: please help me how i will get unique id (document_unique_id) properly through php code to the ajax call and make sure that it will work on the server also...